# Video output is messed up on Sunfire X2200

Tags: video

Well I started to play with an old Sunfire X2200 but got my video all messed up. 
I first tried to boot it using a bootable USB but it didn't work, so I used a HDD with a pre-installed Ubuntu Mate on it. 
The system is working but the colors are all messed, this happens only when I am using the OS, when I am at the BIOS the colours are okay.

[image]